# What Marvel MCU and TV show cross-overs have there been?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

Marvel has apparently made it clear that their TV shows are not always canon with its cinematic universe. I understand that even *Agents of SHIELD*, which used to adhere to the MCU quite closely, has now basically become another universe entirely.

Have *other* shows ever tied into the MCU in any meaningful way, or are they all largely separate universes?

Comment: Where have they made it clear that the Netflix series are not cannon in the MCU?

Comment: This is really too broad. List questions are non encouraged unless they can be reasonably scoped and given the sheer number of shows/movies, the list would be exhaustive.

Comment: @Paulie_D It shouldn't be much bigger than the list I already maintain here. And in fact I'm expecting it to be MUCH shorter, as I don't think there are many cross-overs at all: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/65381/4380

Comment: @A.bakker Uh, here: https://wegotthiscovered.com/tv/marvel-tv-shows-separate-mcu/

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Feige never actually said that, they said they were making the new shows connect more to the movies in contrast to the old ones only referencing the movies...this a clickbait article.

Comment: @A.bakker Well he said: “And it all, **for the first time**, will interlink. So, the MCU will be on your TV screen at home on Disney+ and interconnect with the movies and go back and forth. It’s exciting to expand the MCU into even bigger and better heights.”

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt no crossovers but they are still in the same universe as part of the MCU and are currently still considered cannon.

Comment: @A.bakker AoS already tried very hard to interlink/cross-over already, right? I think Feige just never liked Loeb's TV shows. They can be canon if they don't contradict. Still, if you know of references/cross-overs *please* post an answer. I'd love to see them.

Comment: @A.bakker Also, the non-canon thing has supposedly been confirmed elsewhere: https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/102361/3430

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt again nothing officially confirmed just rumors...just like it was " confirmed"  a few weeks ago that Tobey Maguire would be joining the MCU as an alt reality Spider-Man. As of now the shows are still canon, this might change in the future if they want a do-over with characters used in the Netflix series but Marvel would probably not even bother with that.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt AoS has numerous references, but not all that many crossover events. They deal with the aftermath of Thor: The Dark World and look into some of the tech from the aliens in the Avengers, before the main crossover of s1 with Captain America Civil War. In season 2 we briefly see Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch, and the helicarrier Coulson is outfitting is used in Avengers Age of Ultron. Then, other than some references, I think that's it until the end of season 5, which happens during Avengers Infinity War.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106158/which-marvel-tv-episodes-are-related-to-the-mcu-movies

Answer (score 2):

Recently the movie Spider-Man:No Way Home(2021) confirmed what people had been speculating for a long time - that the Netflix shows and the other spider man movies are canon in the MCU.

Including the much anticipated return of Tobey Maguire and Andrew Garfield's respective versions of Spider-Man the movie also included a brief cameo by Matt Murdock from the Netflix Tv Series Daredevil once again played by Charlie Cox further confirming that the Netflix Tv Marvel shows are MCU canon

[image]

Further in the series Hawkeye(2021) yet another character from the Netflix TV show Daredevil appeared namely the character of Kingpin - whose role was reprised by Vincent D'Onofrio.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Marvel hasn't up to now held the TV shows to be completely cannon simply because of the effort of arranging the appropriately time plot crossing.  I recall *Agents of Shield* taking a brief hiatus because its next episode was going to impinge on Thor 2.

There was references to the war on New York and the aftermath. Some of the shorts made around that time connected shield cleanup operations of alien weapons with the plot.  After Thor, the entire team was diverted to London to reclaim potentially dangerous or contaminated alien debris. The fall of SHIELD by Captain America led directly to the plot to bring back Shield.

The Netflix shows referred to the movies' events as well. Kingpin was making a lot of money reclaiming and rebuilding the destroyed New York. A lot of small operators were scavenging. One of those ran into Damage Control who seized all the potential profits, tying all that into the Spiderman plot.

Some of SHIELD's adventures won't happen for hundreds of years, others involve other realities or computer simulations.

Given the rifts in reality Wanda appears to be about to produce, with rumors of multiversal crossovers from various stars. I suspect it'll all be cannon, somewhere, so long as you know which universe you're talking about. Like one of the ones with Loki and the Tesseract running free. Or where Wolverine is a key player in the X-Men. One where Wanda meets Pietro, just not hers, etc.